# Encountered an inconsistent behaviour while using Flutter DateTime and Timer

Tags: flutter, datetime, timer, output

I noticed some inconsistency while using Flutter's DateTime class. The Timer and DateTime appear to be inconsistent. When I print the current seconds, I see that the output is not what I expected to see. I need help about this please. Here is my code:

```
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();

    print(now.second.toString());
    print('SENDING POS');
    
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    // 3s over, send the other message

    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();

    print(now.second.toString());
    print('POS DONE');
    print('SENDING REFL');
});

Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    // 3s over, send the other message

    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    print(now.second.toString());
    // 5s over, send the other message
    print('REFL DONE');
    print('SENDING PROJ LINES');
});

Timer(Duration(seconds: 15), () {
    // 15s over, send the other message

    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();

    print(now.second.toString());
    print('PRJL DONE');
    print('SENDING HEIG');
});

Timer(Duration(seconds: 15), () {
    // 15s over, send the other message

    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();

    print(now.second.toString());
    pdps.dismissDataBundleDialog(pdps.context);

    print('HEIG DONE');
});
```

My expected out put should be:

```
    2
SENDING POS
5
POS DONE
SENDING REFL
8
REFL DONE
SENDING PROJ LINES
23
PRJL DONE
SENDING HEIG
38
DISMISS
HEIG DONE
```

But I see this instead:

```
2
SENDING POS
5
POS DONE
SENDING REFL
5
REFL DONE
SENDING PROJ LINES
17
PRJL DONE
SENDING HEIG
17
DISMISS
HEIG DONE
```

How can I fix this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using a then() chain:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();

                  print(now.second.toString());
                  print('SENDING POS');
                  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                    // 3s over, send the other message
                    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
                    print(now.second.toString());
                    print('POS DONE');
                    print('SENDING REFL');
                  }).then((value) => {
                        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                          // 3s over, send the other message
                          DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
                          print(now.second.toString());
                          // 5s over, send the other message
                          print('REFL DONE');
                          print('SENDING PROJ LINES');
                        }).then((value) => {
                              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 15), () {
                                // 15s over, send the other message
                                DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
                                print(now.second.toString());
                                print('PRJL DONE');
                                print('SENDING HEIG');
                              }).then((value) => {
                                    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 15), () {
                                      // 15s over, send the other message
                                      DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
                                      print(now.second.toString());
                                      pdps.dismissDataBundleDialog(
                                          pdps.context);
                                      print('HEIG DONE');
                                    })
                                  })
                            })
                      });
```

Comment: you could also use async and await keywords